# How can i change Menu images in WordPress theme "sliding door" from a dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, themes, dashboard

I have made demo of word press using sliding door theme.

Now how can i change the images of that sliding menu from the dashboard?

Comment: i have made 1 word press blog with free twenty ten theme. then i have download sliding door theme and activate it and it works also..but now i want to change that menu images of that theme .. then how can i change it from dashboard...?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can find your answers in the [F.A.Q. section](http://mac-host.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=373&sid=42d5f87aca7de851415f619ba0fd7354) of the themes dedicated support site.

If your trying to put the sliding image menu in another theme [read this guide](http://mac-host.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=124&sid=42d5f87aca7de851415f619ba0fd7354).